# Tincan LMS forum tracking

Tags: tin-can-api

I am currently using moodle as my LMS, migrating to blackboard shortly. I am currently trying to find an approach to track forum activity using an LRS anyone have any deas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking forum usage in an LMS will require some code in the LMS to track data back to the LRS.

I'm not familiar with Blackboard customisation myself, but for Moodle you can develop a 'Log' type plugin that hooks into Moodle Events triggered by the forum module and issues [Tin Can statements](http://tincanapi.com/statements/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=statements?pmc=em-1).

There are [code libraries](http://tincanapi.com/libraries/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=libraries?pmc=em-1) that make is very easy to send the statements. You may also find this [example Moodle code](https://github.com/garemoko/moodle-report_tincan) helpful.

As you're moving to Blackboard, I suggest this is a good question to ask your contact at Blackboard about.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Thanks for the info, as I feared moodle and blackboard customizations. Time to figure out how to create the wheel :P

Comment: Please keep me updated with your progress andrew.downes@tincanapi.com